# Asp.net insert data with image and then rtrieve it on gridview with image and can be perform edit update and delete on gridview

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to create a registration form by which i can save the data of any person with image(by File upload control) then i have to display all the data on another page on gridview and perform edit and delete operation from gridview.

Comment: Hi Abhi, not sure what you expecting. If you're having an exception or need any code assistance you need to be a little bit informative. Post your code and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: I just wanna solution of display, delete and update image from gridview control.